# how can i solve Error in using getGEOSuppFiles

Tags: r

I am new to R. I wanted to ask if some one can help to find the solution of this error and any suggestions about GEO dataset extracting, unzipping, and reading.

`Error in getGEOSuppFiles("GSE112047") :  Failed to download C:/Users/AKIL/Documents/GSE112047/GSE112047_RAW.tar! In addition: Warning message: In file.remove(destfile) : cannot remove file 'C:/Users/AKIL/Documents/GSE112047/GSE112047_RAW.tar', reason 'Permission denied'`

Comment: Welcome. Which code do you use?